# Large amount of heat generated by AC to DC power supply

Tags: power-supply

I purchased this power supply:

[https://www.amazon.com/Yes-Original-Power-Supply-Security-Camera/dp/B078MN4XQG/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1530044862&sr=8-3&keywords=CCTV+Security+Camera+18CH+12V+15A+180W&dpID=51SEIcuz4xL&preST=_SX300_QL70_&dpSrc=srch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078MN4XQG)

I am running about 15m of LED lights that are rated at a working current of 0.35-1.2A per meter.  In reality they seem to pull more like .6A per meter.

I estimate the total current drain to be between 8 and 10 amps.  This is well under the rated max for this unit.

The unit however gets very hot.  Outside of the metal case reaches 120-135F inside 180 to 195F.  These seems VERY hot for this small of a load.  I can only imagine how much energy is going up in heat.  The entire reason I purchased a more expensive supply would be for the advertised 89% effecenty.

I don't know electronics or physics well enough to know how much heat should be generated by the dissipation of an amp of current.  I was hoping someone could tell me if this power supply is broken, or if this is what is to be expected.

-----------------Update-------------------

I'm not sure what I did, but all of this is due to wiring.

I THINK this is what I had wired:  https://www.tinkercad.com/things/5FPIjvucQ46

However, the drain of each is screwed into the box, no guarantee that they aren't shorted against one another.

This: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/9SnoHMoNnBh Seems to be what I should have done.

I think the wiring was somehow causing an overload, and it to pull more current that just for the LEDs.  I have it re-wired and it is running at about 140F inside and 90F outside.

Comment: 8-10A is a "small load"? Does it have any cooling? Fans? Air circulation?

Comment: 8 to 10a at 12 volts.  The entire supply is rated to 180w @ 120v, so 1.5a on mains.  Seems small to me compared to a hairdryer pulling 10a at mains.

Comment: Hairdryer is blowing all of the heat away. This guy seems to lock it inside.

Comment: The power supply is rated at 180 W and you are consuming (@10A) 120W, so you are using around 70% or it's capability. Assuming the power supply is no more than 80% efficient, the internal power dissipated is around 30 Watts. This is not insignificant, and will result in the power supply heating up. Comparing it to a hair dryer does not add any value.

Comment: Maybe I should put this in terms on watts instead.  It's running at about 120 watts.  Can't get much more inefficient that an incandescent bulb, and this thing seems to be running hotter than a 100w bulb.  When really, total heat dissipation should be 11% max, so 13 watts.  This just seems like a lot more heat than this.

Comment: that's not very hot for power circuitry, and within reason considering the dissipation and efficiency. you might consider venting the outer cabinet to lower temps.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback.  I think I will add some active cooling.

Comment: Warning overload on 15m!!!

Comment: "total heat dissipation should be 11% max" — That assumes you're actually running at 89% efficiency.  Voltage regulators vary in efficiency depending on load with the highest efficiency often (but not always) being at the rated load.  Going higher or (especially) lower in load (output amperage) will reduce efficiency.  See, for example, the diagrams in [this random buck regulator datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/30009610F-1131524.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

150°F (65°C) is not an excessive temperature for a power supply.

You have the supply enclosed in a box where the ambient will continue to increase. As diffidence between the power supply and ambient decreases (ambient increasing) thermal convection to cool the power supply will decrease.

> It's running at about 120 watts. Can't get much more inefficient that
>   an incandescent bulb, and this thing seems to be running hotter than a
>   100w bulb.

Your reference to a 100 W light bulb is appropriate.  Put a 100 W light bulb in a closed box and you have an [easy bake oven](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DI4VN0).  A 100 W bulb gets very hot like 4000°K filament.

A fan from the box or mounting the power supply to the enclosure so it can conduct heat away for the supply would be suggested.

A small, very quiet fan like the $9 [12V, 13.5 CFM, 30 dB Sunon HA60151V3-E01U-A99](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sunon-fans/HA60151V3-E01U-A99/259-1588-ND/3466808)  would likely be sufficient.
[image]

I did not see where the ad you reference specified an efficiency. Actual efficiency peaks at a specific capacity like 95%. Actual is generally less. I find many of the vendors on Amazon lie about such things so I would doubt you have 89% efficiency.

I recommend Mean Well power supplies for pricing, reliability, warranty, efficiency, and distribution.
LINK: [Standard LED driver catalog](http://www.meanwell.com/catalog/led/index.html).

---

### UPDATE

> even at 80% efficiency, that would be a 38 watt bulb, not a 100 watt.
>   I think that would be far too low to generate this temperature level.

The point is heat is being generated with nowhere for it to go. The PSU heat must have a path to the outside air.

The current heat transfer path is by natural convection from the PSU to the air inside the box.  Then conduction from the air inside the box through the steel sides of the box.  Then finally natural convection from the outside surface of the box to the outside air.

The highest thermal resistance is the air between the PSU and the sides of the steel box.

Natural convection cooling between the air in and outside the box requires a difference in temperature to be effective.  The air temperature in the box has to rise to high enough for the difference between the air out side the box is high enough for natural convection cooling to the outside air.

As the temperature of the air inside the box rises the convective heat transfer from the PSU to the air diminishes and the temperature of the PSU rises.

The problem is the heat transfer from the inside air to the outside air is too inefficient.

So either you mount the hot part of the power supply to the box to use conductive heat transfer to the outside of the box and/or improve ventilation which may required forced convection with a fan.

Comment: Point taken on the easy bake oven.  BUT even at 80% efficiency, that would be a 38 watt bulb, not a 100 watt.  I think that would be far too low to generate this temperature level.

Comment: I addressed your comment in an update.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the feedback.  I purchased a small 50mm by 50mm fan that will fit up by the top vent. I'm guessing it will do quite a lot.

Comment: If the fan is on top, it should be sucking air out of the box and there must be sufficient ventilation input from the bottom.  You want the air flow from bottom to top between the door and the PSU, past where the PSU fan and PSU vents are located.

Answer (score 2):

1.2A/m * 15 m = 18A you need a 20A supply.

> - most likely the PSU is sensing Over Current and Protection is in "Hysteretic or Hiccup Mode" and going on off quickly. thus an apparent half current from half brightness. ( Assuming you guessed from brightness and did not actually measure it)

Normally 3S LEDs +R repeated.
Load impedance is too low hence voltage and brightness 18A ideal load 12/18= 0.67 Ohms  , 15A supply thus 10V.   Since 3 LEDs have a threshold of <9V it will be using 1V drop instead of 3V drop from 12V.

> Thus 1/3 brightness due to too low R load of 15 meters of stripleds.  This is consistent with results with power limiting and insufficient power to load all now dumped into supply.    This also means supply is running at low efficiency thus overtemp.  Warning !!!

**The power supply is hurting. (**15A max) Going into protection mode then restarting instantly with apparent over current load, operating inefficiently, with I^2R losses thus self heat has increased exponentially but lower duty cycle.

Also 10m max on most stripleds for daisy chain. So use Short Length of AWG 16 between 2 of 3 reels.

Use any good PC PSU and jumper DC on and use a 5V 5W dummy load if necessary for old designs to self start and regulate properly.

Comment: "Assuming you guessed from brightness and did not actually measure it" Are you talking about the current?  I put it on my bench supply set it to 12v and checked how many amps it was pulling.

Comment: So it was running at 50% expected current in both cases at full brightness or not?  what voltage at the end? From hot PSU? If you please , more data

Comment: I was running 12 volts on my bench supply.  Voltage at the end?  Pretty sure that would be 0 volts.  My bench supply is lab grade with adjustable voltage and current, readouts showing which is limiting and current values.  At 12 volts, the 5m strand was pulling 2.9a.  Like I said, it was voltage limited to 12v, I did turn it up to 14v, and it pulled 3.7a or so.  I have no idea about the brightness as I don't have the equipment to test this accurately.

Comment: But does 12V lab supply give same brightness? Then report this in question.  Specs are too loose on A/m but yours indicate 200mA/m @ 12V + 30mA/m per volt above 12.  Or 52W max @14V so poor cooling is problem as other answer indicated and your spec of 350mA to 1200mA /m is false. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: 3.7a is what I recall.  But I didn't write it down, as I don't want to burn these out.  They are already mounted now.  3 reels of 5 meters cut and soldered to the right lengths for each wall of my room.  I have ordered a new reel and will be happy to give you precise data on amps at 14v when they get here.  I can also test side by side, bench supply and cctv supply.

Comment: Banggood drivers are pretty efficient for the cost but never enclose them unless forced air cooling is free flowing